# php файл вложить в дочернюю тему, прописать путь

Tags: php, wordpress, шаблоны, page

У меня возникли трудности, надо (я так думаю) "xml.php" файл вложить в дочернюю тему. В дочерней теме в "functions.php" прописать путь, чтобы был "xml.php" виден в теме. Как реализовать (может, я вообще не туда думаю)?

Answer (score 0):

> (может, я вообще не туда думаю)?

Не туда. Нужно создать страницу ВП со своим кодом в соответствии с [иерархией шаблонов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86.D1.8B). В странице должны быть все заголовки и футеры (для подключения ВП).
Т.е. нужно скопировать имеющийся шаблон страниц и переименовать этот файл (см по ссылке как). В нём изменить заголовки и вместо вывода контента поместить нужный код.

Comment: Благодарю за оперативность. Думаю XML сбил с толку мой вопрос. Суть токов а: у меня есть тема с дочерней темой, я, агент (перепродаю не свои продукты...) мой партнер предложил поместить на моей стороннице свои предложения и дал мне offers.php. На HTML стороннице все работала а вот на ВП не все так просто. Ну я со всей силой прикручиваю "offers.php" в  к дочерней теме. "offers.php" ну да он лежит в  к дочерней теме, но я его не вижу. Пытался вложить в public_html/ ну да вижу но без  Header,  Footer..Что делать? Я что, вообще по полю пошел. Прошу извинить за не совсем корректную формулировку.

Comment: Вот как раз тело  "offers.php" (без html-заголовков) и поместить в шаблон страницы вместо контента. При необходимости подключить скрипты и стили.